# Unexpected local arg: /rsync

Tags: rsync

I would like to use rsync to synchronise my /rsync folder.

I create the rsync users on my 2 servers and configure the ssh key.

I installed rsync, created /rsync folder put chmod 777 on it.

But when I execute

```
rsync -avz -e ssh rsync@1.2.3.4:/rsync /rsync -p 8682
```

I have

```
Unexpected local arg: /rsync
If arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1246) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

("ssh rsync@1.2.3.4 -p 8682" works)

Comment: This is the format I use, maybe give it a shot: `rsync -avze ssh -p 8682 -l rsync /rsync/ 1.2.3.4:rsync`

Comment: "ssh: connect to host 1.2.3.4 port 22: Connection refused" the port seem not be taken into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p 8682' rsync@1.2.3.4:/rsync /rsync
```